# Trying to apply gradient style to Spinner ProgressDialog

Tags: android, background, progressdialog

I am trying to apply one of my layout to Spinner ProgressDialog's background. But not getting success.
Can anyone help here..

I have @drawable/my_layout defined below. Which I need to apply to Spinner ProgressDialog's background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
  <corners android:radius="5dip"/>
  <gradient android:startColor="#FF0000" android:centerColor="#F86E20" android:endColor="#F2DC40" android:angle="270" />
</shape>
```

And creating progressdialog like:

```
ProgressDialog spinner = new ProgressDialog(this,R.drawable.toast_background_layout);
spinner.setMessage("Kindly Wait...\nFetching latest Murli SMS from server...");
        spinner.setCancelable(false);
spinner.show();
```

But it is not showing up.. What is wrong here?
Appreciate any help..

Comment: Can you try putting your shape inside an item tag and that item tag inside a selector tag...

Comment: Now i putting like:
<selector>
<item>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
  <corners android:radius="5dip"/>
  <gradient android:startColor="#FF0000" android:centerColor="#F86E20" android:endColor="#F2DC40" android:angle="270" />
</shape>
</item>
</selector>

Still not working..

Comment: u have to make custom dialog and put 1 progressbar there..and set the custom dialog background as ur above drawable...http://s24.postimg.org/aqxa2lo6d/Capture2.png

Answer (score 1):

make style for that

```
<style name="CustomDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:background">R.drawable.toast_background_layout</item>

</style>
```

and set this style to your progress dialog.

```
 ProgressDialog spinner = new ProgressDialog(this,R.style.CustomeDialog);
    spinner.setMessage("Kindly Wait...\nFetching latest Murli SMS from server...");
            spinner.setCancelable(false);
    spinner.show();
```

Comment: Thanks Samdroid.. But
It is setting the gradient background for each of the components separately. i.e. background from "spinner", background for "text" etc.. And this is giving the effect as if there are gradient "patches". How can I remove this and show smooth background?

Comment: have u tried this?
spinner.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.toast_background_layout);

Comment: Firstly, it should be "setBackgroundDrawableResource". I have already tried it. It gives the same issue as I mentioned above.
patches of gradients :-( Any solution to this?